# How to convert json array in to the columns table in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have one parquet file ,trying to get the data in to the table. In one column it have json with multiple values. Can someone help me how to do in kusto?

Pasting the json's schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "path": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "partitionValues": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "deviceId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "date": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "deviceId",
        "date"
      ]
    },
    "size": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "modificationTime": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "dataChange": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "stats": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "path",
    "partitionValues",
    "size",
    "modificationTime",
    "dataChange",
    "stats"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, your PQ file contains a column with a JSON of the specified schema. If you want to ingest it as-is, ingest it into Kusto [column with type "dynamic"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic) and query later. If you'd like to ingest just part of this JSON data (like some inner fields), use [ingestion mapping and provide appropriate JSON path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mappings#parquet-mapping).

Another option is to ingest as-is into a source table with a [Retention policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/retentionpolicy#the-policy-object) with SoftDeletePeriod of zero. Define an [Update Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy) with a KQL query and the transformed data will be pushed into a target table.

Comment: So I need to create a child table and using ingest mapping query I should pass source table 1 and source table 2 by using the formate right??I didn’t get you correctly can you show by using the above example in query.

Comment: @divya please explain what are you trying to do, it's not clear. What is the schema of your table? What did you already try? Did you try to ingest your parquet file?

Comment: I am trying to load the parquet file data in to kusto table for that by using data tab by selection blob I loaded my parquet file so the data also ingested but 2-3 columns it’s consist of json data now I need to do the extract it for that I wrote one query.by using the extend all properties I tried but for normal json it’s working but nested json I’m not able to do